# Will not display in list box VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net, function, vba, listbox

So, I'm trying to display the statistics for a soccer teams points scored. 
At the time this is being executed, the arrays have been already filled and what not.
When this form opens, I'd like it to display the maximum, minimum, and average scores....
I want it to get the players name and score for max and min. For example:

```
    Maximum: John scored 9

    Minimum: Joe scored 2
```

Like, i'd be getting the value at strPlayers(i) for the name and intScores(i) for score.
I'm pretty sure I had the functions correct, but, for whatever reason, I can not get it to display anything in the list box upon loading the form!

```
Public Class frmDisplayStatistics

Function FindMaximum() As String
    Dim max As Integer
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    ReDim intScores(intNumberOfPlayers)

    max = CInt(intScores(0))
    For i = 0 To intNumberOfPlayers
        If max < intScores(i) Then
            max = CInt(intScores(i))
        End If
    Next


    max = strPlayers(i) & " scored maximum points of " & intScores(i)


    Return max

End Function

Function FindMinimum() As Integer
    Dim min As Integer
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    ReDim intScores(intNumberOfPlayers)

    min = CInt(intScores(0))
    For i = 0 To intNumberOfPlayers

        If min > intScores(i) Then
            min = CInt(intScores(i))


        End If

    Next


    Return min

End Function

Function FindAverage() As Double
    Dim average As Double
    Dim i As Integer = 0


    average = total / intNumberOfPlayers

    Return average

End Function

Private Sub frmDisplayStatistics_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim max As String
    max = FindMaximum()
    lstStatistics.Items.Add(max)
    lstStatistics.Items.Add("Minimum: " & FindMinimum())
    lstStatistics.Items.Add("Average: " & FindAverage())



End Sub

Private Sub btnOK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

The reason maximum returns a string and minimum and average return a number is because I was trying a different approach, that also did not work. :/

Comment: What value do you get for variable max in the form load event?

Comment: I have no clue because it doesn't display anything.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the functions return correct max and min values, I just don't know how to display them in terms of the arrays!

Comment: ok so its returning you array. i think you cant add array like this. You need to loop them

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are getting array in the variable max in the form load event. Then you should loop the array. Like below

```
for i = 0 to max.count -1
     listbox.item.add(i)
 next
```

Also you need to declare variable max as array. Hope you got my point

Comment: The arrays are  strPlayers(intNumberOfPlayers) and intScores(intNumberOfPlayers).

max, min, and average are integer values representing the max, min, and average of the players scores.

Comment: You said that it is returning you array. I asked what value you get in variable max